# How can I save output image from camera directly to file without compression?

Tags: android, camera, sms

After compressing the file and then texting it, it recompresses again and is very choppy

I use Intent to bring up the camera.  I get the result and bring up Intent to send as text.

```
private void takePic() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 2);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 2) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        File file = writebitmaptofilefirst("route_image",photo);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        fileToDelete = file;
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra("address", "8001111222");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        sendIntent.setType("image/jpg");
        startActivityForResult(sendIntent,3);
    }
    else if (requestCode == 3){
        if (fileToDelete.exists()) fileToDelete.delete();
    }
}

public static File writebitmaptofilefirst(String filename, Bitmap source) {
    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File mFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory + "/temp_images");
    if (!mFolder.exists()) {
        mFolder.mkdir();
    }
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    File file = new File(mFolder.getAbsolutePath(), filename + ".jpg");
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
        file = new File(extStorageDirectory, filename + ".jpg");
        Log.e("file exist", "" + file + ",Bitmap= " + filename);
    }
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        source.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("file", "" + file);
    return file;

}
```

This works great except the resulting image texted is choppy.  If I send the same pic that ends up in the Gallery it converts that down and the result is 100 times better at the receiving end.  Can I save the Bitmap I get from the camera call directly without compression, the file will be deleted after the sending of the picture.  The user actually takes the pic and then hits the send button on the default sms app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save an image directly without compressing use [AndroidBmpUtil](https://github.com/ultrakain/AndroidBitmapUtil/blob/master/src/com/ultrasonic/android/image/bitmap/util/AndroidBmpUtil.java):

```
new AndroidBmpUtil().save(source, file);
```

Comment: That did work better but still very small file and very choppy

Comment: This method saves the image as it is untouched .. if it is small and choppy, then it's probably the image itself.

Comment: I have figured out some thing and set up the code as per my understanding but when i run the app it doesn't run and gives me error `Error:(39, 30) error: cannot find symbol method getWidth()` ,` Error:(40, 31) error: cannot find symbol method getHeight()` , `Error:(62, 18) error: cannot find symbol method getPixels(int[],int,int,int,int,int,int)` These all are in `AndroidBmpUtil` If you know how to solve this issue kindly tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
source.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, outStream);
```

use

```
source.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
```

JPEG is a lossy format hence the choppy result.

Comment: Thanks. I tried those and they are still choppy.  I think what I get into Bitmap photo may be already choppy