# Save photo to SD no create file

Tags: java, android

I'm trying the following:

```
1. Click a button to take a photo.
2. Save photo.
3. Add photo into the gallery.
4. Show photo into an ImageView.
```

`1` and `4` works fine, but I'm having problems with `2` and `3`.

This is my code:

```
photoFile = createImageFile();

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = timeStamp;
    File imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), imageFileName + ".jpg");

    mCurrentPhotoPath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();

    return imageFile;
}
```

With this I have a filePath created where I want to store the image.

Now I call the `Intent` with extra params to store the image:

```
if (photoFile != null) {                   
    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),
                     "es.antonio.prueba.fileprovider",
                     photoFile);
     takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
    startActivityForResult(takePhotoIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
 }
```

Now, in my `onActivityResult` I call a function to add the photo into the gallery:

```
private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    getContext().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

And another one to set the photo into the `ImageView`:

```
private void setPic(ImageView mImageView) {
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

I'm struggling with save the picture taken into the SD because my method is not working (I'm followind Android Developers tutrial). I thought that passing an extra to the Intent should do te the trick but it's not working.

Any hint?

Comment: Permissions in manifest written?

Comment: Yes, added for camera and read/write external storage

Comment: `createNewFile();` returns true or false. You are not checking the return value. Please add code to do so and toasts to inform the user.

Comment: please go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47412992/taking-a-picture-with-a-camera-intent-and-saving-it-to-a-file/47413309#47413309

Comment: @greenapps if the image is set into the ImageView it's because the file is created correctly, no?

Comment: @user7348352 this code save a compressed image, I want to save it full sized

Comment: `With this I have a file created where I want to store the image.`. You should not already create that file. Leave creation to the camera app that you invoke. You only need a path to a file -that does not have to exist-.

Comment: @greenapps  so I need to the avoid `imageFile.createNewFile();`?

Comment: `it's because the file is created correctly, no? `. Yes and no. It can be that it is not created by your app but by the camera app. But again: your app should not try to create that file already. So remove createNewFile() indeed.

Comment: `struggling with save the picture taken into the SD `. There is nothing in your code that has anything to do with a removable micro SD card. Your code uses getExternalStorage... And thats not the SD card.

Comment: Further i do not understand your strugling. If the picture is set then all works isnt it?

Comment: The picture is set in the imageView but when I stop the app the file is not in my filesystem

Comment: you can save images without compress=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730365/how-can-i-save-output-image-from-camera-directly-to-file-without-compression

Comment: @greenapps I have deleted createfile but still not working

Comment: The camera app should save the picture to the file you indicated. Only if the camera app saved the picture to file you can later construct a bitmap from that file and set that bitmap to an image view. So if you see that picture in that imageview saving works.

Comment: `when I stop the app the file is not in my filesystem`. Please tell exactly what you do if you search for a file on the file system.

Comment: @greenapps I check the gallery and filesystem with file explorer and the picture is not saved

Comment: Checking with the Gallery app makes no sense. Well not yet. And what do you mean with 'file explorer'. Which one? Where?

Comment: ES file Explorer into sd and internal. Check with gallery have sense because the method galleryAddPic should update the gallery and show the new picture

Comment: Using ES File Explorer app is ok. Now did you find the Pictures directory? Why arent you telling what you see? I keep asking  for info. Tell complete path of Pictures directory please.

Comment: Got it! Thanks dude! It was a miss call to the file provider

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:** It was a miss call to the FileProvider

Updated `createImageFile()`function:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = timeStamp;
    File album = getAlbumStorageDir("MiBodaAPP");
    File imageFile = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", album);

    mCurrentPhotoPath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();

    return imageFile;
}
```

Update `onActivityResult`:

```
takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "es.antonio.prueba.fileprovider", photoFile));
```

Here, I was taking the value `EXTRA_OUTPUT` param incorrectly because I was getting the path from the Environment and not form the FileProvider.

Comment: `File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", album);`. Wrong! Bad! Do not create that file already. You only need a file name/path. Your original code was ok.

Comment: Android Developers Tutorial to take photos make this and now is working... :S

Comment: Yes i know that it comes from that tutorial. How wrong and bad they can be such tutorials!